# How to efficiently get a multivalue diagonal of a non-square matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

Imaging that I have the following matrix `A(5x20)`:

```
    A = [6.4475 3.3487 Inf 6.4940 6.5480 3.4857 Inf 6.5030 6.5035 3.5732 Inf 6.4951 6.6372 3.3639 Inf 6.5371 Inf 4.4444 Inf Inf;
         6.6761 2.3999 Inf 6.8620 6.5776 2.1963 Inf 6.8535 6.8733 3.1184 Inf 6.8688 6.5918 2.2900 Inf 6.8656 Inf 4.4667 Inf Inf;
         5.9808 4.1965 Inf 5.8950 6.2467 4.5779 Inf 5.9116 5.9198 4.0071 Inf 5.8938 6.3981 4.3019 Inf 5.9570 Inf 4.3433 Inf Inf;
         5.7438 1.5369 Inf 5.9868 5.5404 1.6374 Inf 5.9537 6.0332 2.1704 Inf 6.0024 5.5235 1.5035 Inf 5.9397 Inf 3.5727 Inf Inf;
         4.0544 3.8845 Inf 4.1466 4.6749 4.6560 Inf 4.3833 3.7550 3.0591 Inf 4.0693 4.9586 4.1296 Inf 4.6826 Inf 2.5593 Inf Inf];
```

then I would like to extract the values in the following way:

[image]

so my output matrix is:

```
B = [6.4475 3.3487 Inf 6.4940;
     6.5776 2.1963 Inf 6.8535;
     5.9198 4.0071 Inf 5.8938;
     5.5235 1.5035 Inf 5.9397;
     Inf 2.5593 Inf Inf]
```

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Comment: Can you explain with more details how do you take the elements? Is the number of elements per line a parameter?

Comment: yes it should be a parameter, an offset that I should be providing each time. In the case I am showing this offset is 4 starting from the first line. @RodrigodeAzevedo this matrix can be quite big therefore I would like to avoid the `for` loop overload if possible and get a vectorized alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the number of elements per line is a parameter `k`.

In one line, you can retrieve the elements like this:

```
B = A(sub2ind(size(A), repmat((1:size(A,1)).', 1, k), (1:k)+((1:k:size(A,2))-1).'));
```

Let's explain a little. You create the indexes of the elements you want to retrieve and convert them into linear indexing with `sub2ind`. Line indexes are easy to create with `repmat`.

For column indexing, one solution is to create a matrix with elements being the column indexes. Here I choose a long version:

```
(1:k)+((1:k:size(A,2))-1).'
```

It enables you to skip or duplicate elements (depending on `size(A,2)` being a multiple of `k` or not). Note that this construct works in recent Matlab versions, in old versions, you nned to call `bsxfun(@plus, 1:k, ((1:k:size(A,2))-1).')`

If you are sure to take exactly one element per column in the result, let's do it more efficiently:
    reshape(1:size(A,2), k,[]).'

Note that it does not take care of odd sizes of input matrix (if you have more rows for example).

Comment: you are missing a `)` at the end of `repmat`. But still I noticed that `sub2ind` complaints about sizing.

Comment: Should be ok now, right parenthesis added. Tested on R2017.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
% Define the data sample...
A = [
  6.4475 3.3487 Inf 6.4940 6.5480 3.4857 Inf 6.5030 6.5035 3.5732 Inf 6.4951 6.6372 3.3639 Inf 6.5371 Inf 4.4444 Inf Inf;
  6.6761 2.3999 Inf 6.8620 6.5776 2.1963 Inf 6.8535 6.8733 3.1184 Inf 6.8688 6.5918 2.2900 Inf 6.8656 Inf 4.4667 Inf Inf;
  5.9808 4.1965 Inf 5.8950 6.2467 4.5779 Inf 5.9116 5.9198 4.0071 Inf 5.8938 6.3981 4.3019 Inf 5.9570 Inf 4.3433 Inf Inf;
  5.7438 1.5369 Inf 5.9868 5.5404 1.6374 Inf 5.9537 6.0332 2.1704 Inf 6.0024 5.5235 1.5035 Inf 5.9397 Inf 3.5727 Inf Inf;
  4.0544 3.8845 Inf 4.1466 4.6749 4.6560 Inf 4.3833 3.7550 3.0591 Inf 4.0693 4.9586 4.1296 Inf 4.6826 Inf 2.5593 Inf Inf
];

% Define the script parameters...
k = 4;
n = size(A,2) / k;

% Create the auxiliary matrix for indexing...
aux = repmat({ones(1,k)},1,n);
idx = blkdiag(aux{:});

% Extract the elements using the indexing and properly reshape the result...
B = reshape(A(logical(idx)),k,size(A,1)).'
```

The final output is:

```
B =
    6.4475  3.3487  Inf  6.4940
    6.5776  2.1963  Inf  6.8535
    5.9198  4.0071  Inf  5.8938
    5.5235  1.5035  Inf  5.9397
       Inf  2.5593  Inf     Inf
```